# Is there a way to install a tub such that it can dry out if water gets behind it?

Tags: leak, bathtub

When you install a tub, you try to build the surround such that water can't get through to the wall. That's great.

Nothing is perfect, and eventually small amounts of water will seep through. Then the water will be trapped in the wall or floor, and have a hard time getting out.

Is there a way to install a tub so it can dry out behind & underneath?

Comment: I disagree with the premise of the question.  If you properly build the surround, water will never seep through.

Comment: I decided to remove my downvote because while the premise is bad, the question itself is good for showing the bad premise...

Comment: If the tub and surround is installed properly, there is no reason for water to seep behind it. Sorry Jay, but you gotta stop the leak, not dry it afterwards.

Comment: Claw Foot free standing tub. Any splash is easily taken care of with a mop. Now you know why they had a long popularity in previous eras where good sealants were hard to come by.

Comment: @shirlockhomes: Is there any way to ensure that a contractor didn't leave any leaks?